# Android Studio e Google Maps API - Alterar Travel Mode

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Opa galera, beleza? Então, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando o Android Studio e a Google Maps API. Então me deparei com uma questão que, até então, não consegui encontrar nada que pudesse solucionar o meu problema.
É o seguinte, estou trabalhando com Rotas e por padrão o Google maps utiliza a rota "Driving" ao criar o JSON para montar a rota no app. Eu gostaria de alterar esse "travel mode" padrão para outras opções como bicicleta, corrida, trem e etc.
Alguém já se deparou com isso e por um acaso conseguiu resolver?

Essa é a minha classe:

```
private void criarUrlGoogleDirections(){

    urlGoogleDirections = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" +
            latLngPontoPartida.latitude + "," + latLngPontoPartida.longitude +
            "&destination=" + latLngPontoFinal.latitude + "," + latLngPontoFinal.longitude +
            "&waypoints=";

    for (int i = 0; i < objListaLatLngWaypoints.size(); i++) {

        urlGoogleDirections += objListaLatLngWaypoints.get(i).latitude
                + "," + objListaLatLngWaypoints.get(i).longitude;

        if ((i+1) < objListaLatLngWaypoints.size()) {

            urlGoogleDirections += "|";
        }
    }

    urlGoogleDirections += "&sensor=false";

    Log.i("URL", urlGoogleDirections);

}
```

Comment: Como você está a obter a rota?

Comment: Estou utilizando um método chamado "urlGoogleDirections" para criar uma url de acordo com os pontos de Origem, Destino e Pontos de Referência definidos no mapa. Há uma classe chamada JsonRota que faz a conexão com servidor e baixa a Rota de acordo com o Google maps.

Comment: Coloque na pergunta essa parte do código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa, Boa noite pessoal.
Consegui resolver o meu problema da seguinte maneira:
Após a linha "urlGoogleDirections += "&sensor=false";", tive que adicionar o "urlGoogleDirections += "&mode=bicycling";", para montar rotas utilizando Bicicletas como meio de transporte. O Tipo pode ser alterado para qualquer outro disponível no Google Maps. Só dar uma olhada na documentação da Google Api onde trata sobre Travel Mode.
Espero ter ajudado.
Abraço.

Meu código final ficou assim:

```
private void criarUrlGoogleDirections(){

    urlGoogleDirections = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" +
            latLngPontoPartida.latitude + "," + latLngPontoPartida.longitude +
            "&destination=" + latLngPontoFinal.latitude + "," + latLngPontoFinal.longitude +
            "&waypoints=";

    for (int i = 0; i < objListaLatLngWaypoints.size(); i++) {

        urlGoogleDirections += objListaLatLngWaypoints.get(i).latitude
                + "," + objListaLatLngWaypoints.get(i).longitude;

        if ((i+1) < objListaLatLngWaypoints.size()) {

            urlGoogleDirections += "|";
        }
    }

    urlGoogleDirections += "&sensor=false";
    urlGoogleDirections += "&mode=bicycling";

    Log.i("URL", urlGoogleDirections);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma opção eu acho que assim:

travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode].

Onde tem selectMode, seja lá como você recebe, você coloca DRIVING, WALKING, BICYCLING ou TRANSIT.

Mas sem aspas duplas se não me engane.

Comment: Opa Dávil, na verdade na url do Google Directions não possui essa opção que você mencionou, mas consegui resolver o meu problema da seguinte forma:
No meu método criarUrlGoogleDirections, após a implementação do "sensor=false", incluí também o modo que desejava.